# How To Detect a custom object using python?

Tags: python, opencv

Basically, I'm trying to get OpenCV to detect a custom object and click it.

I haven't tried anything I don't have a clue on how to start this and I have tried to do some research but I'm stuck.

Find this object https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGv57.jpg and click it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need CNN ( convolutional neural network ) or RCNN ( recurrent convolutional neural network ) so you can try to google about Tensorflow / Keras, maybe grab some object detection examples from their git repo for research or remake them for your task.

Also, it depends, whether you want to find this object on a video or picture, should it be in live mode or not.

Comment: I thought so just needed a bit more context thanks I’ll look into it when I get some time.